# Treeview LoadFromFile in Delphi 2009 not populating correctly

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-2009

With Delphi 2009 when using TreeView.LoadfromFile only populates the first letter of the first item:
Ie using the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TreeView1.Items.Add(  nil,  'Folder' )
    if SaveDialog1.Execute then
     TreeView1.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
     TreeView1.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
end;
```

Results in Treeview being populated with an F,  Looking at the file created the whole word Folder is present.  Could find only one other reference to this in searches which hinted at possible unicode problem but gave no further information.

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately you've hit the tree view [`issue`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=67220). Since it seems it's not in any of the D2009 patches, you will have to follow some workaround. Fortunately OP of the bug report provided one and maybe someone here come with another.

Comment: @TLama: Not sure if this is the same problem - modified ComCtrls as per Workaround in [link](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=67220) given and recompiled with no change to my problem.

Comment: I do not have D2009 so I cannot test.  If it is encoding issue, you can try using SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName,TEncoding.UTF8) as well as LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName,TEncoding.UTF8); so that you save and load in same encoding for sure.  You can change the UTF8 to the real encoding you needed.

Comment: @Justmade, good point, but rather with `SaveToStream` and `LoadFromStream`. Delphi 2009 doesn't have encoding capability in file manipulation functions yet. Paul, I've tested it, but haven't tried that workaround. But as Justmade said using streams with encoding specified will most probably resolve your problem.

Comment: @Jutmade thanks for the suggestion, did try different encodings but this did not solve the problem.  After continual searching did find a Solution through [Link](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using/200809/080926307.html)